# Subir multiples archivos con Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estoy intentando realizar una subida de archivos a travez de angular, tengo casi todo terminado pero me da muchos errores.

**Aqui mi ensayo**
**

### CODIGO 1

**
Tengo el siguiente codigo html que si funciona:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('SubirArchivos', function($scope, $http, $parse) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.files = [];

  //a partir de aqui el codigo no funciona como deberia
  $scope.upload = function(element) {
    //aqui comienza el codigo de funcion para subir archivos
    console.log("intentando subir");
    angular.forEach(element[0].files, function(item) {
      console.log("intentando subir");
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', item);
      $http.post(item.url, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      }).then(function(success) {
        console.log("subido " + success.data.data);
        return success.data.data;
      });
    });
    // aqui finaliza la funcion encargada de subir archivos         
  };

});

app.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.ngFileModel);
      var isMultiple = attrs.multiple;
      var modelSetter = model.assign;
      element.bind('change', function() {
        var values = [];
        /*if (files != null)
         element.push(files);*/
        angular.forEach(element[0].files, function(item) {
          if (item.name.endsWith("mp3")) {
            var value = {
              name: item.name,
              size: item.size,
              url: URL.createObjectURL(item),
              _file: item
            };
            values.push(value);
          }
        });

        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (isMultiple) {
            modelSetter(scope, values);

          } else {
            modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>prueba</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="SubirArchivos">
    <input type="file" webkitdirectory directory ng-file-model="files" multiple />
    <button type="button" ng-click="upload();">Subir archivos</button>

    <p ng-repeat="file in files">
      {{file.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### CODIGO 2

y la función que si me funciona a subir archivos, que es sin angular seria la siguiente:

**Este seria el codigo JS:**

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                    var modelSetter = model.assign;

                    element.bind('change', function(){
                        scope.$apply(function(){
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('file', file);
                $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                }).then(function(success){
                    console.log("subido "+success.data.data);
                    return success.data.data;
                  });                
            }
        }]);
app.controller('SubirArchivos', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.name = 'World';
            $scope.files = []; 
            $scope.upload = function () {

        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

            $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                console.log('file is ' );
                console.dir(file);
                var uploadUrl = "/upload/";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };

        }]);
```

**Y el siguiente codigo es HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="SubirArchivos">
          <form method="post" id="uploadForm" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
        <p ng-repeat="file in files">
          {{file.name}}
        </p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="startButton">Empezar a subir</button>

        </form>
        </div>
```

En el Código 1 se puede apreciar que al seleccionar una carpeta, se seleccionaran todos los archivos mp3 encontrados en esta y todas sus sub-carpetas. En el Código 2 se puede apreciar que funciona muy bien pues tengo un servidor empotrado en un proyecto que tengo, el codigo funciona muy bien para una solo archivo, pero quiero subir todos los seleccionados dichos anteriormente.
Mi idea es sacar el Código 2, y pasarla al Código 1 como función *upload*
Al hacerlo me encuentro con muchos problemas y no lo he logrado, alguien me puede ayudar? gracias

Comment: No sería mejor utilizar algún plugin? En mi caso he implementado [Bootstrap File Input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-advanced-usage-demo) con Angular y me funciona a la perfección =)

Comment: si esta bien, no es mala idea pero el problema en si es subir los archivos, digamos que es lo que ahora no funciona, ahora me pondré a investigar gracias